# R - running commands in terminal and saving output to a dataframe

Tags: mysql, r, macos, terminal

On OSX, I am using the system() function to run commands in terminal from the R console as part of a script I've written. The script requires connecting to a MySQL() database through an ssh tunnel, and I type into the command line "ps aux | grep ssh" to see what tunnels i am connected to. For example, some output:
.

```
> system("ps aux | grep ssh")
Home            50915   0.0  0.0  2501204   3264   ??  S    10:32AM   server info
Home            50092   0.0  0.0  2504172   3048   ??  Ss    9:35AM   server2 info
Home            50090   0.0  0.0  2501372    480   ??  Ss    9:35AM   server3 info
Home             1155   0.0  0.0  2544220   1368   ??  S    Thu07PM   server4 info
Home            51333   0.0  0.0  2434840    800   ??  S    11:00AM   0:00.00 grep ssh
Home            51331   0.0  0.0  2438508   1124   ??  S    11:00AM   0:00.00 sh -c ps aux | grep ssh
```

.
I would like to turn this output into a dataframe, but cannot. Functions like `as.data.frame(system("ps aux | grep ssh"))` do not work as how I would hope them to work.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated!

EDIT - just wanted to highlight error from one suggested comment

```
> read.table(pipe("ps aux | grep ssh"))
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 34 elements
> pipe("ps aux | grep ssh")
        description               class                mode                text              opened            can read           can write 
"ps aux | grep ssh"              "pipe"                 "r"              "text"            "closed"               "yes"               "yes"
```

Comment: What you have there is just raw text that needs to be parsed as a data.frame. Try `read.table(pipe("ps aux | grep ssh"))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First pipe your output to an actual text file:

```
> system("ps aux | grep ssh") > output.txt
```

Then read in this file into R using `read.table`:

```
df.output <- read.table(file="output.txt", header=FALSE, sep="")
```

Note: Using `sep=""` (which is the default for `read.table` actually) will treat any type/amount of whitespace as a delimeter between columns.  This should cover the output you are getting from your call to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a little closer (to a character vector) with `intern=TRUE`:

```
as.data.frame(system("ps aux | grep ssh", intern=TRUE))
```